# What does 'note: expanded from macro 'bool' #define bool _Bool' mean?

Tags: c, boolean

I have looked and looked and I don't know what this error means. I am trying to write a C program that determines whether a triangle is valid, but when I make it in the command line it seems to tell me something is wrong with bool. I have really spent some time on this and I am just not sure how to get this to run.

[image: Here is my code]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post all code inside the question itself rather than linking to an image, which can go down over time and isn't easily copyable/verifiable.

Answer (score 3):

`bool` is a macro that expands into `_Bool`, it's defined in `<stdbool.h>`.

So when you write:

```
if (bool valid_triangle)
```

it's treated as if you'd written:

```
if (_Bool valid_triangle)
```

That's not valid syntax. `_Bool` is a type specifier, and the way to cast an expression to a type is to put the specifier in parentheses. So it should be:

```
if ((bool)valid_triangle)
```

But `valid_triangle` isn't a variable, it's a function. And it's already declared to return `bool`, so you don't need to cast it. That should actually be:

```
if (valid_triangle(a, b, c))
```

Comment: And the second declaration of `valid_triangle()` inside `main()` isn't really necessary or desirable.